# curl: (26) couldn't open file "/C/Users/sekim/Downloads/Letter to Mama Vincent.pdf"

Tags: curl

I can't figure it out why I am getting the error

```
curl -X POST --user "apikey:<<key>>" --form "file=@/C/Users/sekim/Downloads/Letter to Mama Vincent.pdf" --form "source=en" --form "target=fr" https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v3/documents?version=2018-05-01
curl: (26) couldn't open file "/C/Users/sekim/Downloads/Letter to Mama Vincent.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the way you've formatted the reference to the `C:` drive.

Try this:

```
curl -X POST --user "apikey:<<key>>" --form "file=@C:/Users/sekim/Downloads/Letter to Mama Vincent.pdf" --form "source=en" --form "target=fr" https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v3/documents?version=2018-05-01
```

(Also: Probably better not to post your API key on a question here)